# Spreading values across a week, weighted to start of the week

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a number of shipments per week. I don't want them all scheduled for the Friday. I want to split it over the week

E.g. if I have 9 lots to ship next week I want 2 on day1, 2 on day2 and then 1 per day for the rest of the week.
I have tried cumulative sum and had a very similar issue with other data that I solved with nested for loops but its weighting the lots to the start of the week that has me struggling with this one. I have tried row_number and dividing by the days which gets splits the days but not in a looping motion

```
-- Creates table 1
(SELECT 'SHIP1' SHIP_ID, '202014' SHIP_WK FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHIP2', '202014' SHIP_WK FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHIP3', '202014' SHIP_WK FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHIP4', '202014' SHIP_WK FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHIP5', '202014' SHIP_WK FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHIP6', '202014' SHIP_WK FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHIP7', '202014' SHIP_WK FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHIP8', '202014' SHIP_WK FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHIP9', '202014' SHIP_WK FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHIP10', '202015' SHIP_WK FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHIP11', '202015' SHIP_WK FROM DUAL) SHIPS
-- Creates table 2
(SELECT '202014' WEEK, '7' NO_DAYS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '202015' WEEK, '5' NO_DAYS FROM DUAL) WEEK
```

I need it to say SHIP1 and SHIP2 go on day 1 of week 202014 and SHIP3/4 go on day 2 and then one a day after that.
SHIP10/11 go on day 1 and 2 of 202015 and then 3 days with NULL shipping info.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly your question but couldn't you do that with the Ntile function?  https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/oracle-ntile/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NTILE()` analytic function is exactly what you need.

```
with
  ships (ship_id, ship_wk) as (
    select 'SHIP1' , '202014' from dual union all
    select 'SHIP2' , '202014' from dual union all
    select 'SHIP3' , '202014' from dual union all
    select 'SHIP4' , '202014' from dual union all
    select 'SHIP5' , '202014' from dual union all
    select 'SHIP6' , '202014' from dual union all
    select 'SHIP7' , '202014' from dual union all
    select 'SHIP8' , '202014' from dual union all
    select 'SHIP9' , '202014' from dual union all
    select 'SHIP10', '202015' from dual union all
    select 'SHIP11', '202015' from dual)
,  weeks (week, no_days) as (
    select '202014', 7 from dual union all
    select '202015', 5 from dual
  )
select s.ship_id, s.ship_wk,
       ntile(w.no_days) over (partition by s.ship_wk, w.no_days 
                              order by s.ship_id) as day_no
from   ships s left outer join weeks w on s.ship_wk = w.week
;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
SHIP_ID   SHIP_W DAY_NO
--------- ------ ------
SHIP1     202014      1
SHIP2     202014      1
SHIP3     202014      2
SHIP4     202014      2
SHIP5     202014      3
SHIP6     202014      4
SHIP7     202014      5
SHIP8     202014      6
SHIP9     202014      7
SHIP10    202015      1
SHIP11    202015      2
```

This is looking from the "ship" end and allocating days of the week. In your original post you are also talking about NULL for days of the week that are not used; that can be added, but then it's not clear from which side you are looking at the output. Do you need to know which ships go on each day of each week, or do you need to know for each ship, on which week and which day of that week they need to be shipped?